# Problem while implementing my own OpenID provider and client

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, authlib

I am using [authlib](https://authlib.org/) library(python) which is for client side and [Oauth2](https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/overview/openid-connect/) for the serverside.
after `resp = oauth.get('userinfo')` step my client side code stops and I get this error shown in the browser:

`{ "message": "HTTPSConnectionPool(host='test.*****.com', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /sample/user (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1129)')))" }` 
and here is my code for Oauth client side:

```
oauth = oauth.register(
    'oauth',
    client_id=env.get('client_id'),
    client_secret=env.get('client_secret'),
    access_token_url=env.get('access_token_url'),
    access_token_params = None,
    authorize_url=env.get('authorize_url'),
    authorize_params=None,
    api_base_url=env.get('api_base_url'),
    userinfo_endpoint = env.get('userinfo_endpoint'),
    client_kwargs={
        'scope': 'openid',
    },
)
```

```
@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return oauth.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri='http://localhost:3000/callback')

@app.route('/callback')
def callback_handling():
    oauth.authorize_access_token()
    resp = oauth.get('userinfo')
    userinfo = resp.json()
    print('resp: ',vars(resp))
    return redirect('http://localhost:3000/dashboard')
```

What could be the possible problem? where should I check? server side or client side? Do you have any clue?

Comment: It looks like your Oauth provider (test.*****.com) is returning a bad URL. Something like `https://test.*****.com:8000` but it should actually be `http:...`.

Comment: @DavidK.Hess I looked for it and as you mentioned there was a problem at the provider side so I fixed it by disabling all HTTPS redirects